# Typescript never in type signature

Tags: typescript, generics, types

Take this interface

```
export interface OperationStream<In, Out, Context> {
```

Take this declaration

```
const : OperationStream<never, boolean, ConnectionContext & { userId: string }> = ...
```

This all compiles great.

This of course, does not. Makes sense to me.

```
const exactOp: OperationStream<never, boolean, void> = registerOp
```

So why in the world does the following compile?

```
const exactOp: OperationStream<never, boolean, never> = registerOp
```

PS.
This is what the official docs say:

> The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type; however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, never (except never itself). Even any isn’t assignable to never.

Comment: `never` is a valid type - you can use it wherever any other type can be used.

Comment: @zerkms could you go a little more in-depth? I still don't quite get it, but I feel close to getting it

Comment: It's not clear actually why you think it should not compile. It compiles because there is no reason it shouldn't.

Comment: @zerkms I think it's not supposed to compile because `ConnectionContext` does not extend `never`

Comment: You've actually quoted the answer already: _The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type_. So `never` will fulfill any type constraint (even if you'll define one)

Comment: @AlekseyL. duuhh, that makes perfect sense now. You worded it perfectly to get though to me. Thanks.